# How to select rows of a dataframe periodically with an offset?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to select rows of a dataframe every nth hours. I could use `df[::int(period)]` but I don't know when the timeserie starts. Also, I need to apply an `offset` to the `period`, so assuming my dataframe starts at midnight it gives:

```
period = 6 

offset = 0
hours = [0, 6, 12, 18]

offset = 3
hours = [3, 9, 15, 21]
```

How could I do that with the minimum of lines?

This is how my dataframe looks like:

```
2020-05-06 00:00:00+00:00  0
2020-05-06 01:00:00+00:00  1
2020-05-06 02:00:00+00:00  2
2020-05-06 03:00:00+00:00  3
2020-05-06 04:00:00+00:00  4
2020-05-06 05:00:00+00:00  5
2020-05-06 06:00:00+00:00  6
2020-05-06 07:00:00+00:00  7
2020-05-06 08:00:00+00:00  8
2020-05-06 09:00:00+00:00  9
2020-05-06 10:00:00+00:00  10
2020-05-06 11:00:00+00:00  11
2020-05-06 12:00:00+00:00  12
2020-05-06 13:00:00+00:00  13
2020-05-06 14:00:00+00:00  14
2020-05-06 15:00:00+00:00  15
2020-05-06 16:00:00+00:00  16
2020-05-06 17:00:00+00:00  17
2020-05-06 18:00:00+00:00  18
2020-05-06 19:00:00+00:00  19
2020-05-06 20:00:00+00:00  20
2020-05-06 21:00:00+00:00  21
2020-05-06 22:00:00+00:00  22
2020-05-06 23:00:00+00:00  23
```

For example with period 6 and offset 0 I would like:

```
2020-05-06 00:00:00+00:00  0
2020-05-06 06:00:00+00:00  6
2020-05-06 12:00:00+00:00  12
2020-05-06 18:00:00+00:00  18
```

With period 4 and offset 2 I would like:

```
2020-05-06 02:00:00+00:00  2
2020-05-06 06:00:00+00:00  6
2020-05-06 10:00:00+00:00  10
2020-05-06 14:00:00+00:00  14
2020-05-06 18:00:00+00:00  18
2020-05-06 22:00:00+00:00  22
```

This is how I manage to do this but this method isn't flexible and it doesn't support offset after 23.

```
df.loc[[ind for ind in df.index if
                       (ind.hour == 0 + offset) |
                       (ind.hour == 6 + offset) |
                       (ind.hour == 12 + offset) |
                       (ind.hour == 18 + offset)
                       ]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import date
# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'num':np.arange(0,23+1),
                  'date':pd.date_range(date(2020,5,6),periods=23+1,freq='H')})
df = df.set_index('date')

df.loc[df.shift(offset).dropna()[::period].index]
```

Comment: Thanks it really help

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what u r after : [pandas date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

if the number of hours is 6 and no offset:

```
#set the date as index
df = df.set_index(1)
#get the very first and last dates from the index :
start = df.index[0]
end = df.index[-1]

df.loc[pd.date_range(start=start,freq='6H',end=end)]

                            2
2020-05-06 00:00:00+00:00   0
2020-05-06 06:00:00+00:00   6
2020-05-06 12:00:00+00:00   12
2020-05-06 18:00:00+00:00   18
```

if there is an offset of 2 and number of hours == 4 :

```
df.loc[pd.date_range(start=start + pd.offsets.Hour(2),freq='4H',end=end)]

                            2
2020-05-06 02:00:00+00:00   2
2020-05-06 06:00:00+00:00   6
2020-05-06 10:00:00+00:00   10
2020-05-06 14:00:00+00:00   14
2020-05-06 18:00:00+00:00   18
2020-05-06 22:00:00+00:00   22
```

my column labels are 1,2.(occurred when reading in the data via clipboard)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
print (s[(s.index.hour - offset)%period==0])
2020-05-06 00:00:00     0
2020-05-06 06:00:00     6
2020-05-06 12:00:00    12
2020-05-06 18:00:00    18
Freq: 6H, dtype: int64
```

and with period 4 and offset 2

```
period = 4
offset = 2
print (s[(s.index.hour - offset)%period==0])
2020-05-06 02:00:00     2
2020-05-06 06:00:00     6
2020-05-06 10:00:00    10
2020-05-06 14:00:00    14
2020-05-06 18:00:00    18
2020-05-06 22:00:00    22
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, is the 0 in `period == 0` the first hour we look for the next period? I just realized that answer from @MarcoCerliani is more appropriate in my case because one of my dataframe starts at 23 so I would like hours 23, 5, 11, 17 with period = 6 and offset = 0

Comment: @Florent The code you give was not doing the same as the accepted answer, but if it fits more you need, then glad you found a solution to your problem :)